# Modal inserted into a datatable shows only first record of the table

Tags: php, mysqli, bootstrap-modal

I built a datatable where below the action item, clicking the edit button opens a modal which shows all the details related to the customer that was clicked on.

The problem is that for each customer shown in the modal, there are only details related to the first customer entered in the client table, why?

code:

```
       <?php
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

        <!--Table body-->
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1" class="label-table"></label>
                </th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['nome_cliente'] ;?></td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['cognome_cliente'] ;?></td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['azienda_cliente'] ;?></td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['telefono_cliente'] ;?></td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['email_cliente'] ;?></td>

                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <a href="#modifica_cliente=<?php echo $row['id_cliente']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegisterForm" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-rounded">MODIFICA</a>  
                <?php include('modali/modifica.php'); ?>
                </td>



            </tr>


        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
        <!--Table body-->
    </table>
    <!--Table-->
</div>
```

modal code:

```
<?php
$query_client=mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT * FROM ca2_2ac_clienti WHERE id_cliente='".$row['id_cliente']."'");
$details=mysqli_fetch_array($query_client);
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Modifica <?php echo $details['nome_cliente'].$details['cognome_cliente'] ;?></h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" value="<?php echo $details['nome_cliente'] ;?>" class="form-control validate">
                    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Nome Cliente</label>
                </div>
                <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="orangeForm-email" value="<?php echo $details['cognome_cliente'] ;?>" class="form-control validate">
                    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-email">Cognome Cliente</label>
                </div>

                <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="orangeForm-email" value="<?php echo $details['azienda_cliente'] ;?>" class="form-control validate">
                    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-email">Azienda Cliente</label>
                </div>


                <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="orangeForm-email" value="<?php echo $details['telefono_cliente'] ;?>" class="form-control validate">
                    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-email">Telefono Cliente</label>
                </div>



                <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="orangeForm-email" value="<?php echo $details['email_cliente'] ;?>" class="form-control validate">
                    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-email">Email Cliente</label>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button class="btn btn-deep-orange">Sign up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to my question is that the  tag must have its own #id_modal and the modal must have the same id of the tag  obviously do not forget the include if the modal is on another page . Good coding to everyone

Answer (score 0):

`data-target` must equal a id of the div with data of the client:

`data-target="#modalRegisterForm-<?= $row['id_cliente'] ?>"`

But if you'll have 5-10 clients on the web page, then it's OK. But what if it will be 50 or maybe 100+ users per page? The HTML code will be huge. In this case, you should write a function to dynamically build the HTML for the modal window. You can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22321959/7663972) as an example.