# passing variable in modal?

Tags: node.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have written an function of `nodemailer` which as below :-

```
app.post('/sendemail', (req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  ;
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail ',

    auth: {
      user: 'atul.11192@gmail.com',
      pass: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Enquiry from datadock" <atul.11192@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: 'atul.11192@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Datadock Enquiry ', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

    res.render('contacthanks.ejs', {
      message: 'Email has been sent'
    });
  });
});
```

now upon success i want to display a modal (or popup) displaying success or error can anyone tell me how can i pass some information in the modal and show success or failure ?

Comment: Success or error for the sendMail call?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313992/dynamically-build-twitter-bootstrap-modal). So you could do this

```
function doModal(heading, formContent, strSubmitFunc, btnText) {
    var html = '<div id="modalWindow" class="modal hide fade in" style="display:none;">';
    html += '<div class="modal-header">';
    html += '<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>';
    html += '<h4>' + heading + '</h4>'
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="modal-body">';
    html += '<p>';
    html += formContent;
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="modal-footer">';
    if (btnText != '') {
        html += '<span class="btn btn-success"';
        html += ' onClick="' + strSubmitFunc + '">' + btnText;
        html += '</span>';
    }
    html += '<span class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">';
    html += 'Close';
    html += '</span>'; // close button
    html += '</div>'; // footer
    html += '</div>'; // modalWindow
    $("body").html(html);
    $("#modalWindow").modal();
}


function hideModal() {
    // Using a very general selector - this is because $('#modalDiv').hide
    // will remove the modal window but not the mask
    $('.modal.in').modal('hide');
}

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        doModal("Error", error, hideModal, "OK");
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

    doModal("Message sent: " + info.messageId, "Preview URL: " + nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info), hideModal, "OK");

    res.render('contacthanks.ejs', {
        message: 'Email has been sent'
    });
});
```