# How to update input using Modal confirm multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, modal-dialog

I need to confirm several fields separately after a request. User need to decide between new or old value. Modal is updating input overriding the text and does not wait for confirmation. It only shows at the last event then the confirmation answer is set to all the other ones. I did not find much help on my research and I don't know how to fix it.

```js
var modalConfirm = function(callback) {
  $("#gti-modal-btn-yes").click(function() {
    callback(true);
    $("#gti-modal").hide();
  });
  
  $("#gti-modal-btn-no").click(function() {
    callback(false);
    $("#gti-modal").hide();
  });
  
  $("#gti-modal-btn-close").click(function() {
    callback(false);
    $("#gti-modal").hide();
  });
}

function modalAsk(msg, oldVal, newVal) {
  $('.modal').appendTo($('body'));
  $("#gti-modal-msg")[0].innerHTML = "<h3>" + msg + "</h3>";
  $("#gti-modal").show();
  
  modalConfirm(function(confirm) {
    if (confirm) {
      oldVal = newVal
      alert('Change')

    } else {
      alert('No Change')
    }
  });
}

function funConfirmFields(fieldName, oldVal, newVal) {
  if (newVal !== "") {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      if (modalAsk('Warning!</br>Field: " ' + fieldName.toUpperCase() + '"</br>Old value: ' + oldVal + '</br>New values: ' + newVal + '</br></br>Change to New Value?')) {
        newVal = oldVal
      }
    }
  } else {
    newVal = oldVal;
  }
  return newVal
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtName")[0].value = funConfirmFields('Name', $("#txtName")[0].value, "b",);
  $("#txtDoc")[0].value = funConfirmFields('Doc', $("#txtDoc")[0].value,  "2222");
  $("#txtCell")[0].value = funConfirmFields('Cell', $("#txtCell")[0].value, "456");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="gti-modal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gti-modal-Label" aria-hidden="false" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button id="gti-modal-btn-close" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <p id="gti-modal-titulo" class="modal-title"><i class='fa fa-question-circle pull-rigth '></i> MyModal </p>
      </div>
      <div id="gti-modal-msg" class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="gti-modal-btn-yes" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">yes</button>
        <button id="gti-modal-btn-no" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" value="a"/>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtDoc" name="txtDoc" value= "111"/>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtCell" name="txtCell" value= "123"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured that `bootstrap-modal`does not behave like a `confirm Window` so i could go to [jquery confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) but I prefer to build it Dynamically like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35024966/3638222)

And this is my result:

```js
function addModal( id,  msg, callback) {            
  html =  '<div id="gti-modal-'+id+'" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gti-modal-Label" aria-hidden="false" style="display: none;">';
  html += '<div class="modal-dialog">';
  html += '<div class="modal-content">';
  html += '<div class="modal-header">';
  html += '<button id="gti-modal-btn-close" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>';
  html += '<h3 id="gti-modal-title" class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle pull-rigth"></i> GTI</h3>';  
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="modal-body">';
  html += '<h4>'+msg+'</h4>'
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="modal-footer">';
  html += '<button id="gti-modal-btn-yes-'+id+'" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Yes</button>';
  html += '<button id="gti-modal-btn-no-'+id+'"type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>';
  html += '</div>';  // content
  html += '</div>';  // dialog
  html += '</div>';  // footer
  html += '</div>';  // modalWindow
  $('body').append(html);
  
  $("#gti-modal-"+id).show();    
  $("#gti-modal-"+id).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $(this).remove();
  });
  $("#gti-modal-btn-yes-"+id).click(function () {
    callback(true);
    $("#gti-modal-"+id).hide();

  });
  $("#gti-modal-btn-no-"+id).click(function () {
    callback(false);
    $("#gti-modal-"+id).hide();
  });
  $("#gti-modal-btn-close-").click(function () {
    callback(false);
    $("#gti-modal-"+id).hide();

  });
}



function askModal(id, msg, inputFiel, newValue) {
 addModal(id, msg, function (confirm) {  
  inputFiel.val(confirm ? newValue : inputFiel.val());  
 });
}
function funConfirmField(id, inputFiel, newValue) { 
 if (newValue !== "" && (newValue  !== inputFiel.val())) {
  askModal(id, 'Warning!</br>Field: '+id.toUpperCase() + '</br>New Value: ' +  newValue + '</br>Old Value: ' + inputFiel.val() + '</br></br>Change to New Value?', inputFiel, newValue);
 }
 }



$(document).ready(function () {

  funConfirmField('Name', $('#name'), 'jonh');
  funConfirmField('Doc', $('#doc'), '222');
  funConfirmField('Cell', $('#cell'), '508');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Mark"/>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="doc" name="doc" value= "111"/>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cell" name="cell" value= "617"/>
```